# jquery plugin call public function inside other public function

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I defined my plugin base on http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring

```
(function( $ ){

  var methods = {
    init : function( options ) {  },
    show : function( options ) {  },
    hide : function( ) {  },
    update : function( content ) { 
      // How to call the show method inside the update method
      // I tried these but it does not work
      // Error: not a function
      this.show(); 
      var arguments = { param: param };
      var method = 'show';
      // Error: options is undefined
      methods[ method ].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));  
    }
  };

  $.fn.tooltip = function( method ) {

    // Method calling logic
    if ( methods[method] ) {
      return methods[ method ].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
    } else if ( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) {
      return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
    } else {
      $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.tooltip' );
    }    

  };

})( jQuery );
```

How to call the show method inside the update method?

**EDIT**:

The `show` method references `this`. Using `methods.show(options)` or `methods['show'](Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));` works to call the `show` method but then the reference to `this` seems to be wrong because I got a `this.find(...) is not a function` error.

The `show` method:

```
show: function(options) {
    alert("Options: " + options);
    alert("Options Type: " + options.interactionType);
    var typeCapitalized = capitalize(options.interactionType);
    var errorList = this.find('#report' + typeCapitalized);
    errorList.html('');
},
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
var methods = {
  init : function( options ) {  },
  show : function( options ) {  },
  hide : function( ) {  },
  update : function( options ) { 

    methods.show.call(this, options);

  }
};
```

Comment: I edited the question because now I have a problem inside the `show` method due to a reference to `this`

Comment: Second argument of apply must be an array. So I tried `methods.show.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ) );` with `var arguments = { interactionType: 'Request' };` but now `options` in the `show` method is undefined.

Comment: `arguments` is a special object, don't try and declare your own. Anyway, I edited my question again - use [`Function.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) instead of [`Function.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply). (Sorry I'm not able to test this stuff first, it would help if you had a jsfiddle I could check against)

Answer (score 1):

Your use of `.apply` is what's throwing everything off here. You're deliberately **changing** what `this` means, which is what makes `this.show()` not work. If you want `this` to continue to be `methods` (which makes sense), you can do simply:

```
  return methods[ method ](Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
```