# jQuery plugin storing and using settings on multiple instances

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, slider

I tried creating a plugin for jQuery.

It is a slider with navigation buttons and a nav element, listing the active slide.

I thought I had it all well and working untill I tried using the plugin on multiple instances.
Only the last instance seems to be working, but methods used on the first instance are also triggering the methods for the second instance.

I used an example found here on stackoverflow as a base and continued from there: [jquery plugin call public function inside other public function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5655149/jquery-plugin-call-public-function-inside-other-public-function)

Now it seems something goes wrong with passing the settings, I have tried numerous things and now lost overview of what I am supposed to do to make it work.

I hope this is clear, I have a hard time explaining the issue since it is a little mistery to me. I figured I should create a fiddle to make it more clear: http://jsfiddle.net/NzhnN/

Settings are stored in  `method: { "settings": {},}` and then received by calling `method.settings`. This is where I think something goes wrong.

As you can see, the first instance of the plugin does nothing when the next and previous btn are clicked.

How does one save/edit settings for a specific instance and use these only on that instance. While these are also able to be used by public functions.

Comment: Don't store them in the methods object, instead, store them on the element.

Comment: I tried that, by saving the settings as follows: `this.settings = settings;` in the `init()` function however, upon calling it in a different function e.g `goNext` the `this.settings` returns `undefined`.

Comment: don't store it directly on `this`, instead store it in the elements data. http://api.jquery.com/data

Comment: Also tried that, but when a function refers to another function the data is also `undefined` so `goNext()` can see `$(this).data("foo");` but when `goNext()` does `goNext(){ methods.doSlide(number);` in the method `doSlide`  the `$(this).data("foo");` returns `undefined` again.

Comment: is `this` inside goNext the same as `this` in init?

Comment: @KevinB No, it is not. `this` in click event is the clicked element. This needs to be proxied.

Comment: Also, as others pointed out, settings must be saved per instance, perhaps in `$(this).data('settings')` or in a closure somewhere appropriate.

Comment: @marko yes, I have now. But as mentioned above it goes wrong somewhere. @Kevin B yes, `this` inside `init()` and `goNext()` is the same. In the method `goToSlide` which is called via `goNext()` it returns something different/

Comment: This gets you closer, http://jsfiddle.net/NzhnN/1/ but there's still some issues with the way you're calling the methods, it's inconsistent. When you execute goToSlide, `this` is settings (which isn't good), it should be the element.

Comment: In the latest version I have it all changed to using the data method from jQuery as you suggested. But it seems that if `goNext` calls a method the "this" used in the data method is different. To clarify; http://jsfiddle.net/NzhnN/2/

Comment: I found it, I believe. `methods.goToSlide` should be called using `apply` like:  `methods.goToSlide.apply(this,[options]);` this is because the `this` is outside its scope if it is called by a different method.

Comment: @VincentCohen I noticed that yesterday, and wrote in comment to KevinB. Since this is part of your API, using call/apply is just workaround. The thing should be fixed properly. If you haven't done it yet, I'll take a look at it later today.

Comment: Oh, I thought that using `apply` was correct, did not realise it is not.

Comment: @VincentCohen Using `apply` is correct but not very _nice_ if you are not the only user of your plugin.

Comment: After talking this over with some people it seems my problem lies with the fact that I want to be able to both do `$(".next").jCarousel("goNext");` and at the same time call other methods from e.g `goNext()`. Am I correct in this if I say that is "should" not be possible? So for example "goNext" bindings should be defined by the plugin and not the front-end?

Answer (score 0):

I found the anwser by chance..

When a method calls a different method the `this` falls out of scope. 
The way to fix this is to instead of calling a methods like `methods.doSometing()` use the following: `methods.doSomething.apply(this,[options]);`. This way `this` is added to the scope.